Where are the files located in a Drupal Docker installation?
Someone assisted me in installing Drupal with Docker on my Mac.  (I am new to Drupal and it has been years since I last coded.)  The site works fine.  I would like to set up a custom theme, but when I open VS Code in the installation directory, there are only the following files: .env, .gitignore, docker-compose.yaml.  I don't see a theme directory or anything that I expected.  The docker-compose.yaml file has this in it:
volumes:
- drupal-data: /var/www/html

It looks like all the files should be in /var/www/html.  The problem is that this directory doesn't exist on my machine.  Can someone point me to where the files should be?
Tried:

Looking for /var/www folder on machine.  Does not exist.


The files are probably in /var/lib/docker/volumes/... maybe instead of - drupal-data: /var/www/html, you want something like - .:/var/www/html or - ./web:/var/www/html

I figured it out -- at least to my own satisfaction -- and am adding this note to hopefully help other users.  The code resides in the Docker container of course and you can access it by doing the following:
(A) From the command line run this command:
% docker exec -it drupal bash
Where "drupal" is replaced with the name of your container.  You may have to use "/bin/bash" instead of "bash".  You will then be able to see the files, open them with nano or vi, etc.
(B) Use the Docker extension in VS Code:
Install the docker extension in VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace).  If docker is running it will automatically pick up the containers and allow you to navigate in the folder structure, add files, etc.
HTH.

You can accept your own answer if you answered your own question :)
